# Migrating from AEM 6.2 to 6.5 and updating the Maven archetype problems

Tags: jsp, aem, classnotfoundexception

So the setup is that I am working on migrating an old AEM 6.2 archetype to the AEM archetype 40 with more segmentation of the code and profiles that will build the projects and perform the deployment with one call.

The issue at hand is that all of the components for the 6.2 version are in Classic UI form and based on JSPs. I have been told by management, that there is no funding or current planning to migrate from Classic UI to Touch UI. I know that this is preferable but not allowed at this time. Please don't suggest that because it is not an option at this time.

I have the new archetype building and deploying as expected, however, I am having issues with the JSP compiling. The exception thrown is a ClassNotFoundException that the com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page cannot be found. I've checked the uber-jar.6.5.0.jar file and I do not see the class in that bundle. I have it exporting in my bundles, I've checked them and I see the class there. I have restarted my instance several times and still have the same issue.

What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance.

I have rearranged the Import-Package and Export-Package sections of the POM file, several build cycles, restarted the instance several times. Still nothing is helping.

Comment: If you go to /system/console/depfinder, and enter com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page, what you get? In my 6.5.12 server I see for example the output below, do you have a similar result, is that dependency declared in your pom.xml?
<dependency>
   <artifactId>cq-wcm-api</artifactId>
   <version>5.14.6</version>
   <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>